# What is the `&::` syntax in LESS CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I've been looking at twitter bootstrap and came across some syntax and I do not know what it does:

From [buttons.less](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/buttons.less#L149):

```
button.btn,
input[type="submit"].btn {
  &::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
```

What is the `&::` in `&::-moz-focus-inner` for?

I know the `&` is for a 'parent selector' and that a `:` is part of the syntax for a pseudo selector such as `:hover`, but what is the second `:` for?

*Ps.* I've also been looking for a LESS syntax reference but I cannot find any documentation about LESS other than the one page at lesscss.org. Is there no documenation for LESS other than that one page?

Comment: I'd also like to know if someone has a more thorough reference for the less syntax

Comment: It is hidden under the name ["Language Features"](http://lesscss.org/features/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Copypaste from

http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/05/after-v-after-what-is-double-colon-notation/

> The double colon replaced the single-colon selectors for
>   pseudo-elements in CSS3 to make an explicit distinction between
>   pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements. For backward compatibility, the
>   single-colon syntax is acceptable for pre-CSS3 selectors. So, :after
>   is a pseudo-class and ::after is a pseudo-element.
>
> This :: notation (double colon notation) was introduced by the W3 in
>   order to “establish a discrimination between pseudo-classes and
>   pseudo-elements. For compatibility with existing style sheets, user
>   agents must also accept the previous one-colon notation for
>   pseudo-elements introduced in CSS levels 1 and 2 (namely, :first-line,
>   :first-letter, :before and :after). This compatibility is not allowed
>   for the new pseudo-elements introduced in CSS level 3.” For more
>   information, visit W3.